# Openfire development in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, openfire

I am importing openfire in eclipse. I have done this successfully but I am not able to run that in http://127.0.0.1:9090/. Following is the error I am facing. And I used this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlMaBplFbuQ to import the openfire source in eclipse.

```
    HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Unable to compile class for JSP
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:251)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1359)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:924)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:219)
    ... 51 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just run the server from Eclipse. Build the server using Ant and it will generate whole server in target/ folder.

You can then run openfire server from there. (target/openfire/bin/openfire.sh or openfire.bat)