# Openfire not run on eclipse Error "503 accessing /setup/index.jsp."

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, openfire

I am able to run sucesseful the openfire program well on the localhost in my pc.

But if I run the source code of openfire on eclipse

I got the error **"HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /index.jsp. Reason:
    Service Unavailable"**

In the console eclipse the output after runing the source code are:
**"Openfire 3.9.3 [Aug 26, 2016 8:42:49 AM]
Admin console listening at http://my-localhost:9090"**

What I miss here?
Thanks for Any help.

I figuer out that I have problem with build.xml file

After, Run AS > Ant Build

The new ERROR are:"
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\Root_workspace\V7\openfire\build\build.xml:511: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\Root_workspace\V7\openfire\build\build.xml:519: C:\Android\Root_workspace\V7\openfire\src\web does not exist."

**Something wrong with web path.**

My part of the code Build.xml are:

```
  <!-- jspc ================================================================================== -->
<target name="jspc" depends="compile" description="Compiles all JSP pages in the admin console">
    <mkdir dir="${jspc.dest.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jspc.java.dest.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jspc.classes.dest.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${webapp.dest.dir}"/>

    <antcall target="-jspc-impl"/>
</target>

<target name="-jspc-impl" unless="no.jspc">

    <!-- we're forced to create a temp dir to properly overwrite sources from overlay directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${jspc.jsp.src.dir}"/>

    <copy todir="${jspc.jsp.src.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}"/>
    </copy>
    <!-- copy overlay -->
```

[image: The structure openfire on eclipse.]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running Openfire directly from Eclipse, you should run the server separately. As i have described in this answer:
[Openfire development in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742499/openfire-development-in-eclipse/38742791#38742791)

Once you make changes in source code, just compile it using Ant and re-run the server from target/ directory.

Comment: I am not geting How to "Build the server using Ant and it will generate whole server in target/ folder." did you have link?

Comment: In Eclipse, browse the source code and locate "build.xml" file under build/ folder. Right click on build file and Run As > Ant Build

Then check the console if build is successful or not. For successful build, it will generate Openfire server binary under target/ folder

Comment: It's possible to let Openfire start from Eclipse, it's just tricky and get long to set up the envronment and it's needed to modify the ant to compile it.